# uiview deleted from storyboard is still showing

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a very strange behavior in my ios app, if I go to the storyboard and delete the UIImageView object and then run the simulator it still show the image.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't want to say that I don't necessarily believe you, but I don't necessarily believe you. Things don't appear on the screen all by themselves...

Answer (score 0):

I know why you don´t believe me, I didn´t beleive it either when I saw it, but I just found what(not why) was hapening: the problem was that I messed with the main storyboard configured in the project->info, somehow it was calling the old storyboard and i say somehow because there was no file with that name, it was not enough to change the property to the actual storyboard file, I needed to create a new one.